# Excel VBA: Accessing track changes for a cell via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, tracking

Is there a way to access the track changes information for a cell via VBA? This information is usually displayed by Excel when you hover a mouse over a cell which has been modified. I would like to be able to check the date/time of the last modification.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid assumptions to your question, please be more clear. Specially for the mouse hovering part...
On an answering note, ''IF'' you are asking a method to track changes take place in a particular cell in a worksheet then Cell could be treated as a range and you could use sheetChange event. There are number of simple examples you could easily find. You may try out http://vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=909